# Developer Story asks where I currently work. I don't

Tags: bug, developer-story

The second page of the developer story asks

> Where do you currently work?

I am currently between jobs, so I don't work anywhere. Should it not ask for my current or most recent position?

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I am no HR or experienced interviewer...

While not answering the question of why this is done, to the implied question of what to do, I would say you should consider the ["third option"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TakeAThirdOption).

All kinds of fields to be completed can in my view be used in two ways:

- To search about you (e.g. we need a data scientist with 100 years of experience)
- To get information about what you do.

If a tool is not designed to highlight your assets, fill in the minimum that would make you appear in a search, and use a pointer to a cv / a better site for the rest. This way I think you would appear in a search, and it's up to them to read the details if relevant (also, and as an excuse, at the end of the day there are so many places to maintain your cv and your time is limited.)

Answer (score 2):

There's an easy way to answer this:

> Freelance

I'd put this in there because it at least sounds like you're attempting to work in some fashion. You might not have any clients, but Dev Story doesn't need to know that ;)

Comment: Especially since participation on StackOverflow itself could count as freelancing (writing/fixing code for others in exchange for points, badges, etc.).

Comment: @C8H10N4O2: You made my day! :D

Answer (score -11):

The developer story is effectively a resume (at least, it's one of its primary purposes). For the purpose of a resume, there is a big difference between currently employed and not.

Yet it's not *just* a resume. It's supposed to describe your *developer story* so far -- whether you're currently employed or not. And include all your related experience -- whether it's connected to a job or not. Its focus is not to find employment but to tell others what kind of fellow and professional you are (in particular, you cannot e.g. tailor it for each employer to highlight the points they might be interested in the most).

So, the question as it is does make sense in the Developer Story context, and asking for "current or last occupation" instead would be contrary to its focus.

Comment: Yes - so when I mostly have need of a resumé is when I am not employed.

Comment: @podiluska I dare to object. Wether somebody’s employed or not tells little about the developer's history and what skills to expect. An example: I was unemployed for over a year, living on savings because I chose so. Does this change my set of skills or what I did in the past? If you need a job, simply put a phrase like „Looking for new opportunities“ will do, imho.

Comment: @podiluska In the united states, roughly 50% of hires are made from employment, 50% out of unemployment. Focussing only on the needs of unemployed is unreasonable.

Comment: This statistic is even unconditional. I'd imagine that for high-skilled occupations such as developers etc., the unemployment rate is below average, increasing the share of hires that go to the pool of employed.

Comment: I think you missed the point. The Developer story *assumes* you have a job. IMO such assumptions should not be made. The follow-up discussion about the function of the Developer Story becomes redundant if the assumption is taken away.